# How can I reduce the size of jQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Hi Guys I downloaded a search box suggestion from the link

[Search box suggestion](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

In it there is a .js file  http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js in this link

The .js size of 426kb is the problem. . .Is there anyway that the code inside it can be reduced, 
or is their any easy coding for search box suggestion. . in jquery or else in javascript Please help me out guys.

Comment: Did you customize the download files at http://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.10.3&components=1101000000100010000000000000000000

Comment: yes i customized it. . .its reduced to 263kb, the new file is jquery-1.9.1 but this file is affecting my dropdown select box which is supported by the old jquery.min.js file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, just use the [minified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29) version:

http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js

This is 223kb. Alternatively, you can "roll your own" by clicking http://jqueryui.com/download/ and choosing the required elements that you need.

Comment: The smallest you can get is by doing a custom build (as per the download link above) and then minifying after. Remember that the browser will cache the script so it should only be downloaded once by users of your site.

Comment: Ok lee. . i will customize it. . .

Answer (score 3):

If you are using bower, you can alternatively only select the modules you need, and override the jquery's default on your bower.json file. The override section on your bower.json file would then be:

```
"overrides": {
  "jquery-ui": {
    "main": [
      "ui/core.js",
      "ui/widget.js",
      "ui/mouse.js",
      "ui/position.js",
      "ui/draggable.js",
      "ui/droppable.js",
      "themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"
    ]
  }
}
```

Note that core, widget, mouse and position are required by other modules, so they should be included first (and in that order).

Comment: `core.js` is no longer required from 1.12: https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/15028